# How to achieve a sub-select using the sqlalchemy orm?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

- Album: id, name, ...
- Track: id, album_id, ...

I need to generate the query below using the SQLAlchemy orm:

```
SELECT 
  Album.name,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count
    FROM Track
    WHERE Track.album_id = Album.id
  ) as tracks
FROM
  Album
WHERE
  Album.band = ‘Metallica’ AND
  tracks.total_count > 10
```

The code so far:

```
tracks = session \
  .query(func.count('*').label('total_count')) \
  .select_from(Track) \
  .filter(Track.album_id == Album.id) \
  .subquery()

query = session \
  .query(Album.name, tracks.c.total_count) \
  .filter(Album.band == 'Metallica') \
  .filter(tracks.c.total_count > 10)
```

and the generated query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  Album.name,
  anon_1.total_count
FROM
  Album,
  (
    SELECT count('*') AS total_count
    FROM Track, Album
    WHERE Track.album_id = Album.id
  ) AS anon_1
WHERE
  Album.band = ‘Metallica’ AND
  anon_1.total_count > 10
```

which is much slower. Any ideas how i can return the sub-selected results as part of the root select? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I tried your answer earlier and when I looked at the generated query I realized that is not possible as the whole had to be repeated. bummer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform the query as you'd like, because you cannot use select list items in the WHERE clause predicates, because WHERE is evaluated before SELECT. A plain JOIN, GROUP BY, and HAVING should suffice in this case:

```
query = session \
  .query(Album.name, func.count()) \
  .join(Track) \
  .filter(Album.band == 'Metallica') \
  .group_by(Album.id) \
  .having(func.count() > 10)
```

The query above uses the fact that you should be able to select `Album.name`, even though it is not used in the GROUP BY, because it is functionally dependent on `Album.id`. Of course you could group by name as well, given that no albums share a name.

Your original attempt is slow because instead of a correlated subquery it performs a pre SQL-92 style join in the subquery between albums and tracks, effectively counts all tracks, and joins again between albums and the derived table in the enclosing query.